# Failed to start raise network interfaces & wifi devices say 'device not ready' in the network manager

Tags: networking, wifi

I'm trying to get the wifi working on my raspberry pi but the devices say 'device not ready' and when the pi boots it says failed to start raise network interfaces. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

I try /etc/init.d/networking restart and it says

```
[....] Restarting networking (via systemctl): networking.serviceJob for networking.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status networking.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
 failed!
```

Then when i run systemctl status networking.service it says this

```
● networking.service - Raise network interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/networking.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2019-01-07 17:48:59 UTC; 1min 4s ago
     Docs: man:interfaces(5)
  Process: 857 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c if [ "$CONFIGURE_INTERFACES" != "no" ] && [ -n "$(ifquery --read-environment --list --exclude=lo)" ]; then udevadm settle; fi (code=exited, s
  Process: 861 ExecStart=/sbin/ifup -a --read-environment (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 861 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

qun 07 17:48:59  ifup[861]: /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant: 2: /etc/wpa_supplicant/functions.sh: Status:: not found
qun 07 17:48:59  ifup[861]: /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant: 3: /etc/wpa_supplicant/functions.sh: Priority:: not found
qun 07 17:48:59  ifup[861]: /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant: 4: /etc/wpa_supplicant/functions.sh: Section:: not found
qun 07 17:48:59  ifup[861]: /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant: 5: /etc/wpa_supplicant/functions.sh: Installed-Size:: not found
qun 07 17:48:59  ifup[861]: /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant: 7: /etc/wpa_supplicant/functions.sh: Syntax error: newline unexpected
qun 07 17:48:59  ifup[861]: run-parts: /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant exited with return code 2
qun 07 17:48:59  systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
qun 07 17:48:59  ifup[861]: ifup: pre-up script failed
qun 07 17:48:59  systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
qun 07 17:48:59  systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
```

The only thing in the `/etc/network/interfaces` file is auto lo iface lo inet loopback. I had the wifi configured from the widget in the taskbar. It was working fine before, but my raspberry pi shutdown after a power loss during an apt upgrade and now the wifi doesn't work.

Comment: Have you set the country code? If yes, what does ```sudo rfkill list all``` tell us? If not, then you **MUST** set the country code to get WiFi active.

Comment: My country code is set to US & the output of rfkill list all is 0: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
1: phy1: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
2: phy2: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no

Comment: So you need to free up those interfaces with ```sudo rfkill unblock all```. Then the GUI widget in the taskbar should be able to configure your SSID/password. Note: it won't work if your access point is using WEP security.

Comment: rfkill unblock all didnt do anything unfortunately they still say 'device not ready'. When I did rfkill list all they already said soft blocked: no.

Comment: Do you use `/etc/network/interfaces` to configure wifi? Please address me with @Ingo otherwise I wouldn't see your reply.

Comment: @Ingo No the only thing in the interfaces file is auto lo iface lo inet loopback. I had the wifi configured from the widget in the taskbar. It was working fine before, but my raspberry pi shutdown after a power loss during an apt upgrade and now the wifi doesn't work.

Comment: Hmm... that's bad. Maybe you have to (re-)install packages/drivers that are broken during failed upgrade. Do you have the possibility to connect the RasPi to the internet, e.g. with an ethernet cable?

Comment: @Ingo I just connected the pi through ethernet to my pc and I'm running apt upgrade now so hopefully when it's done the wifi will work, I'll check back here when it's done.

Comment: Most of those commands wouldn't work, because Raspbian doesn't use `networking.service` Note you should include the significant information "my raspberry pi shutdown after a power loss during an apt upgrade" in your question. Your best bet is to restore from your backup.

Comment: @Milliways it is said in the question. You should read it carefully.

Comment: @Ingo Most of the question, the comments and the answer are a red herring, because the only significant information was omitted and only included in the comments. It is unclear which "it" you claim I didn't read.

Comment: @Milliways Only for feedback from my view and with respect: it does not help much always only claiming missed information. As you may experienced since years it seems to be fighting a losing battle. We have many novices not familiar with technical communication. I always try to read between the lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you had an interrupted upgrade it may be possible that it has broken your wifi setup. As said in the comments you are able to connect to the internet with an ethernet cable. First you should "finish" the upgrade with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt update
rpi ~$ sudo apt full-upgrade
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl reboot
```

Raspbian does not use *networking* with ifupdown by default so it does not make sense to restart its service. The unmodified `/etc/network/interfaces` looks like this:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
```

You should check why you have a modified *interfaces* file.

Another step could be to check the wifi setup how it is explained at [Setting WiFi up via the command line](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md). Don't forget to set the country code.