# Pi Zero Fails to Raise Network Interfaces

Tags: networking, wifi, pi-zero-w, kali

I recently installed Kali Linux on my Raspberry Pi Zero W and following [this guide](https://www.zdnet.com/article/hands-on-kali-linux-2018-1-on-the-raspberry-pi-zero-w/) connected it to my local WiFi network. I was able to connect just fine on the first try as well as the second try and I could update all of my packages using `apt-get` as well as try to download a file with `wget`.

Then after shutting down the Pi for a couple of days, I got back to it and tried to change the WiFi network to another in my house, but after trying to connect it wouldn't and I realized that I was actually connecting to a 5Ghz WiFi network, one which the Pi Zero W [doesn't support](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=215621).

I then changed my configuration settings back to the old WiFi SSID and password and rebooted, but my Pi wouldn't connect back to the network. I re-tried multiple times to no avail. I continued to get the following output and subsequent errors every time I boot up the Pi:

```
[OK] Starting Network Manager
     Starting Hostname Service
[OK] Started WPA Supplicant
[OK] Started Authorization Manager
[OK] Started Modem Manager
     Starting Raise Network Interfaces...
[OK] Started Hostname Service
brcmfmac: power management disabled
[FAILED] Failed to start Raise Network Interfaces
See "status networking.service" for more details.
[OK] Reached Target Network
     Starting /etc/rc.local Compatibility
     Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell Server
     Starting Permit User Sessions
```

I had never seen the `[FAILED] Failed to start Raise Network Interfaces` line until after I tried connecting to the different WiFi network.

This is what I have set in my `/etc/network/interfaces` config file:

```
iface lo inet loopback
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-ssid homewifinetwork1
wpa-psk Password1
```

I searched the internet for quite some time and tried multiple solutions, none of them working. So I have turned to asking my own question, hoping it will help me figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following answer on [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/92780/failed-to-start-raise-network-interfaces-wifi-devices-say-device-not-ready-i?rq=1) (in the comments) and on the Raspberry Pi Forums [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=188891), but I am sharing it to be of use to anyone who might stumble upon my question above.

First, run the command `sudo rfkill list all` and you should get something like this:

```
0: phy0: Wireless Lan
Soft Blocked: no
Hard Blocked: no
```

Then, run the command `sudo rfkill unblock all` and reboot using `shutdown -r now`. I am told this won't work if you have a WiFi network that uses WEP security.

Then open `/etc/rc.local` in a text editor and add the following two lines before `exit 0` at the bottom:

```
sleep 10
sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

Save the file and reboot by typing `shutdown -r now` and when your Pi comes back up, it should be reconnected to the WiFi network.